# Content > Design >Config shows no records on fresh 2.1.3 install

Tags: magento2

Fresh install of Magento 2.1.3 with Lumo sample data has no records to edit in Content > Design > Configuration.

How can I fix this?
[image: result of insert]

[image: Config > Themes pages]

Answer (score 5):

A better way to fix this is to run the reindexer command:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid
```

This will update the `design_config_grid_flat` with the correct values for your site. If you get a message that the index is locked you may need to reset it with:

```
bin/magento indexer:reset design_config_grid
```

Answer (score 2):

May be , your magento instance does not installed properly that why it is created issue.

IN magento 2.1.3 ,`Content > Design >Config section` does not exit.

You can see at ,`Content>Configuration>Design Configuration`

You can see theme assignment at **Content > Theme >Config**

Please check design_config_grid_flat table data.

If does have then run this query

```
INSERT INTO `design_config_grid_flat` VALUES ('0',NULL,NULL,NULL,''),('1','1',NULL,NULL,''),('2','1','1','1','');
```

Comment: Thank you I inserted the line you quoted as the table had no rows in it...this then gave me the option to change the header information etc...but upon viewing the store none of the new information is visible..Im adding a second pic so you can see the result of the insert...I have the Luma sample data installed so was expecting to see that change